# Why are repeated letters skipped in some strings?

Tags: python, for-loop, indexing

this code is meant to 'explode' a given string s

```
def string_splosions(s):
    """erp9yoiruyfoduifgyoweruyfgouiweryg"""
    new = ''
    for i in s:
        new += s[0:int(s.index(i))+1]
    return new
```

For some reason this code can return the correct 'explosion' for most words however words which have a repeated letter they do not print correctly.
examples.

Correct outputs is would be:

```
Code --> CCoCodCode

abc  --> aababc

pie  --> ppipie

incorrect outputs when s is

Hello --> HHeHelHelHello (should be HHeHelHellHello)
```

(Note: in the incorrect output there should be 1 more l in the second to last repeat.)

Comment: Please do not post pictures on stack overflow when asking a question, but instead post the actual code in your question, formatted properly.

Comment: [**Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: [`s.index(chr)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.index) returns: "Return the lowest index in s where the substring sub is found". So everytime you search for `a` in `aaa` it finds the first one.

Answer (score 3):

You should transcribe the code instead of posting a picture:

```
def string_splosion(s):
    new = ''
    for i in s:
        new += s[0:int(s.index(i))+1]
    return new
```

The problem is that index(i) returns the index of the first instance of that character, which is 2 for both l's in "Hello".  The fix is to just use the index directly, which is also simpler:

```
def string_splosion(s):
    new = ''
    for i in range(len(s)):
        new += s[:i+1]
    return new
```

Or even:

```
def string_splosion(s):
    return ''.join(s[:i+1] for i in range(len(s)))
```

Comment: Recursively: `return string_splosion(s[:-1]) + s if len(s) > 1 else s` :)